# Strange socket problems

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have a server I wrote using Asynchronous sockets. In the piece that accepts new connections I am getting a problem where some users are saying that some of the times they get this error on the server when the client tries to re-connect to the server:

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

After this error occurs the server goes dead and no new clients can connect until I physically quit the server program and start it again. So what should I do when I get this error? I tried to essentially restart the server in my code by closing the socket (listener.Close()) and then calling the same code I used to create and bind to the socket in the beginning, but then I get an error saying that I can't bind to the same port again.

So, two questions. First off, what is the proper way to handle that error and prevent it from essentially killing my server? Next, what is the proper way to restart a server through my code? Just calling .close() on the listener and then starting it again doesn't work in this case.

Thanks

### Here is the code that accepts the connection request

Private Sub connectionRequest(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)

```
    Try

        Dim thisListener As Socket = CType(ar.AsyncState, Socket)

        Dim handler As Socket = thisListener.EndAccept(ar)

        Dim remoteEndPoint As IPEndPoint

        remoteEndPoint = handler.RemoteEndPoint

        thisListener.Listen(10)

        thisListener.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf connectionRequest), thisListener)

        thisListener.NoDelay = True

        thisListener.Ttl = 32

        Dim state As New StateObject

        state.workSocket = handler

        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf dataArrival), state)

        handler.NoDelay = True

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you Dispose of the Listener as well as call Close?  It may not acutally release the socket until the listener is disposed.

Comment: I did this exactly:
listener.close()
listener = Nothing
Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us the code that you have for accepting connections?

You shouldn't have to restart your server. You should just fix the bug in your accept code in your server.

Clients can and will experience this problem when a server isn't accepting connections quickly enough, and/or if the listen backlog queue is too short for the rate at which new connections are being established and at which the server is accepting them.

Comment: I posted it above. Also, the server is only accepting 1 client connection at a time.

Comment: Er, you only need to listen once... Not each time you post an async accept. All you need to do in there with the ListenSocket is the new BeginAccept().

Comment: Thanks, we made the change and are testing it now. Will let you know if it works.